# Should recv() result must be equal to buffer length?

Tags: c++, winsock, recv

```
int resp = recv(s, buf, len, flags);

if(resp == 18) {
    char data[18];
    strcpy(data, buf);
    ...
}
```

I expect strlen(data) to be equal 18, but it isn`t. What did I miss?

Comment: `recv`'s size parameter is the *maximum* number of bytes it can write back.  If the data arrives in bits and pieces, you might get back partial data and need to make a second call to `recv` to read the rest.

Comment: The data from recv() is probably not NUL terminated.  Add buf[resp] = '\0'; and your data[] array is too small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `data` contains a zero-byte `\0`, then `strlen` will only give you the length of the string up to the terminator. If `data` does not have a terminator, then `strlen` will continue searching through whatever memory it happens to be at. This is commonly used in [buffer overflow attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: Thank you, input indeed contains zero-bytes

Comment: If the data has null bytes in it, then use the return value of `recv()` to know how many bytes are actually in the buffer, don't rely on other functions like `strlen()` for that info.

Answer (score 2):

I think what Joe is trying to say is your code isn't bullet-proof, starting with the number bytes read and copying the data into the data array.

```
int resp = recv(s, buf, len, flags);
if(resp > 0) 
{
  // ! This code assumse that all the data will fit into 18 bytes.
  char data[18];  
  memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));  

  // ! As Joe warned above, this code assumes there's a null terminating 
  // ! character in the buf you received.

  strcpy(data, buf);  // consider memcpy if binary data (i.e. not strings)
}
```